# rviz dies with ogre exception in groovy

Tags: rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am testing groovy. Running "rosrun rviz rviz" gives me:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::InternalErrorException'what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/include/pass_depth.geom Cannot compile GLSL high-level shader : rviz/include/pass_depth.geom (1) : error C0201: unsupported version 150 (5) : error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying depth in GLSLProgram::compile at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLSL/src/OgreGLSLExtSupport.cpp (line 65) Aborted (core dumped)
```

Device Name: Quadro FX 3700/PCI/SSE2
Driver Version: 2.1.2.0

The driver is the binary driver Ubuntu 12.04 gives me.

Any ideas about this? Is the driver to old?

EDIT:

2013-02-07:

Just updated to new packages. I had to re-install the graphic drivers and I then made sure to take the recommended version (might have had version 173 before). And now rvix starts OK for me and no error messages. So either I had the wrong driver version or the recent update of the groovy packages solved the problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51671/rviz-dies-with-ogre-exception-in-groovy/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) on 2013-01-09**:
I have met a similar issue,           python: /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/OgreMain/include/OgreSingleton.h:80: Ogre::Singleton::Singleton() [with T = Ogre::LogManager]: Assertion `!ms_Singleton' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-02-07**:
This was definitely a problem with rviz gracefully degrading on OS X.  Please mark an answer so it shows up as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try again with the newest version of rviz, we recently fixed a similar error on OS X:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/558

EDIT:

You can get the latest rviz by updating and rebuilding your workspace:

```
cd ~/ros_catkin_ws
wstool merge -t src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop --merge-replace
wstool update -t src
```

This command will prompt you for action at each of the packages which have changed, choose 'b' for backup and replace on each of them.

Then rebuild the stack:

```
rm -rf build* devel*
./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install
```

It is necessary to rebuild all of the packages because it is likely many packages (not just rviz) have changed and may affect rviz.

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2013-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-01-25**:
So how do I build the latest version? I tested downloading a zip file from the github and build in a workspace but it included files from /opt/.../rviz which seems wrong. So what are the steps to build it?

**Comment by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) on 2013-01-25**:
I updated my answer.